# Processing the precompiled header gives me errors I don’t understand

Tags: objective-c, precompiled-headers

I am building an iOS 4.2+ game using Xcode 4.1 and Pixelwave, on OS X Lion.

At one point during the development, I did a Clean of the project, and ever since I have been unable to compile the project, as I get an enormous number of errors when it processes the PCH. Here is the invocation and the first few bunches of errors reported:

```
ProcessPCH /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceLanes-hfosxrptdqurkjagubffvwqautju/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/SpaceLanes-Prefix-gsthuuctbvtocahgjvzncaegrttc/SpaceLanes-Prefix.pch.gch SpaceLanes/SpaceLanes-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42
    cd /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/andy/bin:/Users/andy/homebrew/bin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -x objective-c-header -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk -gdwarf-2 -mthumb -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -I/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceLanes-hfosxrptdqurkjagubffvwqautju/Build/Intermediates/SpaceLanes.build/Debug-iphoneos/SpaceLanes.build/SpaceLanes.hmap -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Include -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Common -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Core -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Display -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Events -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Geom -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Loaders -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Media -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Text -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Utils -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/libpng -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/TouchJSON -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/TRE -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/zlib -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Core/Audio -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Core/Visual -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Media/Channels -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Media/Sounds -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Modifiers -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Utils -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Text/FontOptions -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Text/Fonts -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Text/Renderers -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/DataStructures -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/Exceptions -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Utils/Modifiers -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Utils/Regex -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Utils/TextureAtlas -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/include -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/src -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/TouchJSON/Source -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/TRE/lib -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Modifiers/SoundModifiers -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Modifiers/TextureModifiers -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers/FontParser -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers/ParsedData -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers/SoundParser -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers/TextureAtlasParser -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers/TextureParser -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/include/freetype -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/src/base -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/src/cff -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/src/pshinter -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/src/psnames -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/src/raster -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/src/sfnt -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/src/smooth -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/src/truetype -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/TouchJSON/Source/Experimental -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/TouchJSON/Source/Extensions -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/TouchJSON/Source/JSON -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers/FontParser/FontFuser -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers/FontParser/FontParsers -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers/SoundParser/SoundParsers -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers/TextureAtlasParser/TextureAtlasParsers -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers/TextureParser/TextureParsers -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/include/freetype/config -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/include/freetype/internal -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers/FontParser/FontFuser/TextureFontFuser -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/ExternalFrameworks/FreeType/include/freetype/internal/services -I/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Parsers/FontParser/FontFuser/TextureFontFuser/TextureFontFusers -I/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceLanes-hfosxrptdqurkjagubffvwqautju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceLanes-hfosxrptdqurkjagubffvwqautju/Build/Intermediates/SpaceLanes.build/Debug-iphoneos/SpaceLanes.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceLanes-hfosxrptdqurkjagubffvwqautju/Build/Intermediates/SpaceLanes.build/Debug-iphoneos/SpaceLanes.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceLanes-hfosxrptdqurkjagubffvwqautju/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -c /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/SpaceLanes-Prefix.pch -o /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceLanes-hfosxrptdqurkjagubffvwqautju/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/SpaceLanes-Prefix-gsthuuctbvtocahgjvzncaegrttc/SpaceLanes-Prefix.pch.gch

In file included from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Include/Pixelwave.h:74,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/Game/Block.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:42,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:38,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/SpaceLanes-Prefix.pch:12:
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Common/PXSettings.h:99: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
In file included from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/PXTopLevel.h:44,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Include/Pixelwave.h:77,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/Game/Block.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:42,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:38,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/SpaceLanes-Prefix.pch:12:
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/Exceptions/PXException.h:41: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSException', superclass of 'PXException'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/Exceptions/PXException.h:45: error: expected ')' before 'NSString'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/Exceptions/PXException.h:47: error: expected ')' before 'NSString'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/Exceptions/PXException.h:47: error: expected ')' before 'NSDictionary'
In file included from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/DataStructures/PXLinkedList.h:40,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/PXTopLevel.h:51,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Include/Pixelwave.h:77,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/Game/Block.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:42,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:38,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/SpaceLanes-Prefix.pch:12:
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/DataStructures/PXPooledObject.h:50: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
In file included from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/PXTopLevel.h:52,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Include/Pixelwave.h:77,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/Game/Block.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:42,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:38,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/SpaceLanes-Prefix.pch:12:
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/DataStructures/PXObjectPool.h:47: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/DataStructures/PXObjectPool.h:59: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'PXObjectPool'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/DataStructures/PXObjectPool.h:63: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSMutableDictionary'
In file included from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Include/Pixelwave.h:78,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/Game/Block.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:42,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:38,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/SpaceLanes-Prefix.pch:12:
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/TopLevel/PXMath.h:43: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'PXMath'
In file included from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Include/Pixelwave.h:81,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/Game/Block.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:42,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:38,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/SpaceLanes-Prefix.pch:12:
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa/PXView.h:72: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView', superclass of 'PXView'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa/PXView.h:72: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSCoding'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa/PXView.h:80: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'CGSize'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa/PXView.h:84: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'BOOL'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa/PXView.h:85: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'BOOL'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa/PXView.h:86: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'BOOL'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa/PXView.h:87: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'BOOL'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa/PXView.h:112: error: expected ')' before 'CGRect'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa/PXView.h:114: error: expected ')' before 'CGRect'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa/PXView.h:119: error: expected ')' before 'CGRect'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa/PXView.h:123: error: expected ')' before 'UIImage'
/Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Cocoa/PXView.h:129: error: expected ')' before 'BOOL'
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGGeometry.h:9,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Support/Utils/PXGLUtils.h:51,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Core/Visual/PXGL.h:47,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Classes/Display/PXDisplayObject.h:41,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/pixelwave/head/Pixelwave/Pixelwave/Include/Pixelwave.h:84,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/Game/Block.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:42,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:38,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:9,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9,
                 from /Users/andy/dev/spacelanes/src/SpaceLanes/SpaceLanes-Prefix.pch:12:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:91: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'typedef'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:92: error: expected ')' before 'allocator'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:93: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:93: error: 'CFStringRef' declared as function returning a function
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:94: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:94: error: 'Boolean' declared as function returning a function
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:95: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:95: error: 'CFHashCode' declared as function returning a function
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:97: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'CFIndex'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:112: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'const'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:123: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'const'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:149: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'CFIndex'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:163: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'const'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:193: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CFTypeID'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:278: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CFDictionaryRef'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:302: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CFDictionaryRef'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:374: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CFMutableDictionaryRef'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:407: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CFMutableDictionaryRef'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:417: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CFIndex'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:436: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CFIndex'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:452: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CFIndex'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:470: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Boolean'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:486: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Boolean'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:508: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'const'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:533: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Boolean'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:556: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:576: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:596: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:619: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:638: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:652: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDictionary.h:662: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
```

As far as I can tell, nothing had changed in the build settings that would have triggered this.

Here is what I have tried, unsuccessfully, while attempting to debug this:

- Reverting to a previous commit of my project that had previously compiled ok.
- Checking out a fresh copy of Pixelwave.
- Reverting to the first commit of my project that had previously compiled ok.
- Deleting the DerivedData subdirectory for the project.
- Restarting Xcode.
- Rebooting.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling dev tools (I was getting desperate).

None of this has helped—I still encountered the same errors every time. I am at my wits’ end as to what is causing this behaviour. I don’t even know where to start looking.

Comment: Is your Obj-C `#import`s in your PCH inside of `#ifdef __OBJC__` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following a suggestion from another user, I copied all the source files into a new project, and got that to build. Doing a diff of the two project files then revealed one of the very few meaningful differences was `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS`, set to `YES` in the project that wouldn’t build.

Setting `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS` back to the default `NO` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting the "/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/" directory (quit Xcode first)?

My other idea is that there might be something weird (unprintable character?) at the start of your 'SpaceLanes-Prefix.pch' file - although your reverting to an old project should have taken care of that, so it seems unlikely.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted the DerivedData directory, but forgot to mention that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you perhaps added some non-Objective-C files to your project ? This looks like you have a

```
#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

in C or C++ source files (maybe implicitly because it's in the header). You may have to wrap that include in

```
#if __OBJC__
```

statements in the precompiled header to keep it out of files that have no use for it.

Although, the error messages mention protocols and interfaces, so maybe you *are* getting the Objective C compiler for some of those errors.

Comment: The PCH certainly has the `#if __OBJC__` guard around its import. I don’t believe there are any UIKit.h imports elsewhere in the project, but I will check.